# Python Asynchronous Requests in a While Loop

Tags: python, multithreading, asynchronous, python-requests, zeromq

I currently have a program which uses a `while` loop to receive messages as a subscriber from a **`zmq_socket`**. Every time I get a new message, I need to make an HTTP request to a server, which will then send a response. This call takes around 1 second to make. I would like to have a way to call the HTTP request and then loop again, get another message from `zmq_socket`, and call another HTTP request without waiting for the first one.

The pseudo-code would look something like this:

```
url = 'http://example.com'

def callback(message):
    r = requests.post(url, data = message)
    # store r in class variable (not sure how to do this asynchronously) 

while True:
    message = zmq_socket.recv_json()
    callback(message)
    # do other stuff
    # continue without waiting for callback to finish
```

### Is there any way to do this in Python?

I've looked into libraries like `tornado` and `asyncio` as well as looking at `multithreading` and I haven't figured out a solution.

Comment: You can use a https://docs.python.org/3/library/queue.html#queue.Queue to pass `message` to a https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html that executes `callback`.

Answer (score -1):

### Yes, there are several ways to do this in Python :

Their main difference is the cost-of-operations and performance.

**A )**
The simplest and cheapest ever is to use Tkinter-native infrastructure of independent **`.mainloop()`**-orchestrated processing, where independent serial-processing cheaply takes place in a co-orchestrated manner, with additional soft-real-time benefits, if one may wish to use them. Given this option, one may soft-schedule the **`callback`** using either an **`.after()`** or even **`.after_idle()`** ( as your code regularly goes into a blocking-mode of the `.recv()` receiver ) scheduling methods.

**B )**
Another, way smarter Tkinter-native infrastructure tool may do a similar job more efficiently, given the **`message`** would actually become a Tkinter's **`StringVar`**-instance, that has been equipped with a `<aVarTRACER>:<aTracedVarEventHANDLER>`-monitoring-tool. This way any value-change of the **`message`** will auto-trigger a **`callback`**, without the code taking any further steps ( but the correct setup of such `StringVar` monitor ). I love this Tkinter-tool, indeed for many powerful Live-GUI designs.

```
 ##########
 # THEORY :
 # .trace_variable( <mode>, <aTracedVarEventHANDLER> )
 #                  <mode> := { "w": WRITE-DELTA-TRACER    |
 #                              "r": READ-ACCESS-TRACER    |
 #                              "u": UNDEFINE-DELETE-TRACER
 #                               }

 #########
 # SETUP :
 pass;             aMessageVAR = StringVar()
 id_W            = aMessageVAR.trace_variable( "w", \ 
 onWriteChange_var_aMessageVAR ) #             "WRITE"-DELTA-Event <~ callback()
 # + any change of aMessageVAR auto-triggers  onWriteChange_var_aMessageVAR()
 #                                             with 3 params:
 #                                                  aTkNameOfVAR,
 #                                                  aTkArrayIndex,
 #                                                  aTkAccessMode {"w"|"r"|"u"}
 #
 #                                             global       aMessageVAR
 #                                             aLocalCopy = aMessageVAR.get()
 #                                             #LocalCopy content b4 next .set()

 ############
 # ORIGINAL :
 #____________________________________________ original while-loop:
 while True:
                   aMessageVAR.set( zmq_socket.recv_json() )
                   #                                     ^__blocks, better
                   #                                        design
                   #                                        non-blocking .poll()
                   #                                        scheduled with
                   #                                        .after( nMS, aPoll )
                   #                                        + .set() on POSACK'd
 #########
 # FINALLY:
 pass;             aMessageVAR.trace_vdelete( "w", id_W ) # CLEAN THE TRACER
```

**C )**
Last, but not least, one may design a scalable performance ZeroMQ workflow from inside of your **`while`**-loop, where any such received `message` gets marshalled into a pool of remote-workers over another `zmq_task_to_pool_of_workers_socket`. This approach can help easily "mask" the worker-side processing latency by adding more remote-workers into the pool of workers, besides the elementary trick of getting the async `.post()`-method and other associated work done "outside" of the said `while`-loop. The almost linear performance scaling + latency masking of this option may go beyond the shared GIL-lock stepping, so if these are the core design-features, this is the way to go.